# Creating r dataframe with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am new to programming. I am working on a problem where I need to create a dataframe using a function that takes a file directory, and file names, and create a dataframe with the file id, and a summary of cases for each file.

When I run the program with the following parameters, the data frame is built  correctly:

```
function("directory", 1:5)  # or any vector that starts with 1

  id nobs
1  1  117
2  2 1041
3  3  243
4  4  474
5  5  402
```

However, when the parameters are

```
function("directory", 5)
```

I get NAs added in between

```
  id nobs
1  1    1
2 NA   NA
3 NA   NA
4 NA   NA
5  5  402
```

Here the expected result should be

```
 id nobs
1  5  402
```

or

```
function("directory", 3:7)  # id does not start with 1

complete("specdata", 5:10)
   id nobs
1   6    6
2  NA   NA
3  NA   NA
4  NA   NA
5   5  402
6   6  228
7   7  442
8   8  192
9   9  275
10 10  148
```

Here is my code.. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {

    slash <- "/"
    fileext <- ".csv"

    id <- numeric()

    nobs <- numeric()

    for(i in id) {     
            fileid <- as.numeric(i)
            file <- sprintf("%03.f", fileid)
            filename <- paste(directory, slash, file, fileext, sep = "")
            datafile <- read.csv(filename) #read file
            cases <- sum(complete.cases(datafile))


            id[i] <- i
            nobs[i] <- cases     



    fd <- data.frame(id, nobs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
    fd

}
```

My intuition is that  when `id[i] <- i`, i is assigned to the vector position `i`.  When `i` is != 1 it fills in the missing rows with NAs.  I tried different things but can't figure out how to set the index to start at position 1.

Comment: This is obviously from the Peng Coursera homework. You should NOT be modifying the index within a for-loop. You SHOULD be using the course website that has been set up for students to to ask for help.

Comment: It is. I tried that route first but could not get tips to solve the problem the way I am approaching it.   Thank you for the tip about indexes.  It help me understand how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 id <- append(id,i)
```

Also I'm wonder that your code works because `id` variable is reassigned from vector to numeric object.

Comment: I made your suggested changes and now it works like a charm!  I am so happy that I am taking myself out for a beer :-) . Thanks alot!!